# Can I use scikit-learn with Django framework?

Tags: django, scikit-learn, analysis

I would like to make a Web app in which some data is analyzed. Due to it, I read that Django is a good option for doing web apps and that scikit-learn was used for machine learning. Therefore, before starting, does anyone know if it is possible to use that combination?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: The two dimensions, web framework and machine learning libraries, are totally orthogonal. In fact, there's nothing stopping you from using Django with scikit-learn and OpenCV and many other Python libraries…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django is a python framework meaning that you need to have python installed to use it. Once you have python, you can use whatever python package you want (compatible with the version of python you are using).